# Node cannot acess Wordpress Docker container (var/www/html)

Tags: wordpress, docker

I want to run Docker with default `image:wordpress`, custom themes, and plugins. And this works perfectly, but when I want to run node everything works well I see installed packages, runned build etc.

But when I'm entering my files in docker via `docker exec -it [containerID] bash` there is no file in the `public` folder.

Even trying to make some `COPY` command inside `Dockerfile`its not working, it looks like from Dockerfile and node builder I cannot access `var/www/html` which is Wordpress directory.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
    
    services:
        mysql_wordpress:
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress_db"
    
        wordpress:
            depends_on:
                - mysql_wordpress
                - wordpress_frontend_build
            image: wordpress:latest
            ports:
                - "3002:80"
            links:
                - mysql_wordpress:mysql
            env_file:
                - "../wordpress-custom/.env"
            volumes:
                - ../wordpress-custom/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/
                - ../wordpress-custom/my-custom-theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-custom-theme
    
        wordpress_frontend_build:
            build: "../wordpress-custom"
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14 AS builder

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ["./my-custom-theme/src", "./my-custom-theme/src" ]

COPY [ "package*.json", "./" ]
COPY [ "webpack.config.js", "./" ]

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build && rm webpack.config.js

RUN npm prune --production
```

Comment: Can you share error about how it cannot access var/www/html? Because I have tried n my local and it is working.

Comment: @MustafaGüler whats interesting, there is no such errors here. Just build generated by webpack is not "copied" properly into `var/www/html` directory